# When casting an object in Java, is the reference to the original preserved?

Tags: java

For example, if I were to have a class `Utensil` and then I instantiated it like so:

```
Utensil utensil = new Utensil();
```

And then also had a new class `Fork`, and cast `utensil` like so:

```
Fork fork = (Fork)utensil;
```

Is `fork` still referencing the original `utensil` object?

Comment: unless all `Utensil`s are `Fork`s, this code will not even compile. If you change the cast to `Utensil` to a cast to `Fork`, it will fail at runtime instead.

Comment: @JanDvorak I changed the example I gave to match that, I had just mistyped the cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming `Fork` is a subclass of `Utensil`.

A better example would be `Fork` being a subclass of `Utensil`:

```
Fork fork = new Fork();
Utensil utensil = fork;
```

at this point both the variables `fork` and `utensil` are referencing the same object.

Comment: This is what I was getting at, my example was a bit strange. Thank you!

Comment: @AshtonOhms your example will fail at runtime since random `Utensil`s are not `Fork`s

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Casting an object gives you a reference to the same object, but looking at it as the type you casted it to.
(except for boxing conversions)

Comment: @JanDvorak: No; it won't compile.

Comment: ok... after the cast is fixed to cast to `Fork` instead, it will throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is what you really meant. In your example, if Fork extends Utensil, then your code throws an error, since utensil is not a Fork and cannot be assigned to fork.

If you had it this way

```
Fork fork = new Fork();
Utensil utensil = fork;
```

then utensil would still reference the original Fork object. So I guess the answer to your question would be yes.